# How to create different Jenkins2 images , unlocked and with preloaded plugins?

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I launch a new Jenkins2 container based on the [official Jenkins image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md).

But, it needs the initial setup. The random generated unlock string must be entered and the admin user/pass must be set. Then the plugins must be installed.

I want to be able to set these up from the dockerfile.

I made a list of the plugins that I want to be installed during build, but how do I confront the other two?

Basically, I want to be able to create different images uniquely configured and ready to be used via a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Plugins

Installation of plugins (as per the [documentation](https://store.docker.com/images/d55eda09-d7f0-47b0-8780-3407f2f9142c?tab=description)):

```
# Dockerfile

USER root
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

# (...)
USER jenkins
```

If you wish to generate a **plugins.txt**, before running the above, based on your current manual jenkins setup run the following:

```
JENKINS_HOST=<user>:<passwd>@<hostname>:<port>
curl -sSL "http://$JENKINS_HOST/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins" | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\/\w+>)+/\1 \2\n/g'|sed 's/ /:/' > plugins.txt
```

_

```
# plugins.txt (example)

ace-editor:1.1
git-client:2.1.0
workflow-multibranch:2.9.2
script-security:1.24
durable-task:1.12
pam-auth:1.3
credentials:2.1.8
bitbucket:1.1.5
ssh-credentials:1.12
credentials-binding:1.10
mapdb-api:1.0.9.0
workflow-support:2.10
resource-disposer:0.3
workflow-basic-steps:2.3
email-ext:2.52
ws-cleanup:0.32
ssh-slaves:1.11
workflow-job:2.9
docker-commons:1.5
matrix-project:1.7.1
plain-credentials:1.3
workflow-scm-step:2.3
scm-api:1.3
matrix-auth:1.4
icon-shim:2.0.3
ldap:1.13
pipeline-build-step:2.3
subversion:2.7.1
ant:1.4
branch-api:1.11.1
pipeline-input-step:2.5
bouncycastle-api:2.16.0
workflow-cps:2.23
docker-slaves:1.0.5
cloudbees-folder:5.13
pipeline-stage-step:2.2
workflow-api:2.6
pipeline-stage-view:2.2
workflow-aggregator:2.4
github:1.22.4
token-macro:2.0
pipeline-graph-analysis:1.2
authentication-tokens:1.3
handlebars:1.1.1
gradle:1.25
git:3.0.0
external-monitor-job:1.6
structs:1.5
mercurial:1.57
antisamy-markup-formatter:1.5
jquery-detached:1.2.1
mailer:1.18
workflow-cps-global-lib:2.4
windows-slaves:1.2
workflow-step-api:2.5
docker-workflow:1.9
github-branch-source:1.10
pipeline-milestone-step:1.1
git-server:1.7
github-organization-folder:1.5
momentjs:1.1.1
build-timeout:1.17.1
github-api:1.79
workflow-durable-task-step:2.5
pipeline-rest-api:2.2
junit:1.19
display-url-api:0.5
timestamper:1.8.7
```

## Disable Security & Admin user

This can be sorted by passing **--env JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"** to the **docker run** command.

Example:

```
docker run -d --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false" jenkins:latest
```